# Alternative for leveldb_dart package?

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, desktop, leveldb

Is there any way to deal with leveldb in dart?
I found a [leveldb](https://pub.dev/packages/leveldb) package, but its not compatible with current version, ie: 2.17.6. Now I am considering solution for Linux, but will consider Windows also in future.

Comment: can you use rocksdb instead?

Comment: the problem is, I want to sync settings to my new application from existing electron application, so electron use leveldb to store values.